# How to see ping requests being recieved on the destination machine?

Tags: ping

If I have machine A set to ping machine B the request is sent from machine A and is seen by the ping server on machine B and then machine B sends back its response back to machine A. Machine A can then work how long this took etc. All well and good.

**However is there a way that I can see on machine B that a ping request has been received from machine A ?**

Answer (score 3):

Wireshark is the way to go 10/10.

1. Install and run Wireshark.
2. Select the interface you're getting pings on.
3. Use the filter **icmp and ip.src==insert source IP address**

What you're doing here is listening for the incoming ICMP packet which is the ping request and making sure it is from the IP address of the original computer.

Comment: Yes I agree WireShark can see all the ICMP traffic from the pings. However I was hoping to find something less complex as the intended purpose was to provided a simple means for a test engineer to establish that our device is still working while it is being bombarded in an EMC test chamber.

Comment: Honestly, it's not very complex. If all you're needing to do is watching ping packets, Wireshark will do exactly that. It's just a listener and is actually not very complex at all unless you're looking into the packet information, but you can see the packet type from the frame window without investigating.

Comment: Wireshark is too heavy duty for something so simple.  Just use `tcpdump -nn icmp`.  Add `and host 1.2.3.4` if you want to limit it to packets coming from 1.2.3.4.